# Download and build Carthage locally to avoid step in the CI

Tags: ios, carthage, bitrise

I am starting using Bitrise as the CI for my iOS app but I'm on the free version, so the build have to take 10 minutes or less.

The main issue is when Bitrise builds my Carthage dependencies, is there a way where I can prebuild it in local, push everything to my repo so I can completely avoid the Carthage step?

At the moment I'm using `carthage bootstrap`. I have also tried `carthage update --cache-builds`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use rome https://github.com/tmspzz/Rome, this provides a cloud storage based Carthage cache, your Carthage step will pull pre-built binaries from your choice of cloud storage (S3 for instance).